# Best way of redirecting the url in php?

Tags: php, cakephp, curl

I am working on web application(in php),where i require to redirect url with some parameter.I have written a code like this

```
header("Location:http://www.xyz.com?code=2345");
```

This will redirect to corresponding url but the my data is visible in the browser,i don't want my data to be visible in the browser.how to hide the data? Is this the secure way of redirection? What is the best way of redirection?

Comment: Just don't write any output if you're going to redirect (makes no sense to write output and then redirect)?

Comment: He means the variables visible in his url.

Comment: Are you using CakePHP? And what data are you concerned about, the `code=2345` in the URL? Is this secret data?

Comment: Are you redirecting to same domain (xyz.com -> xyz.com) or off domain (abc.com -> xyz.com) ?

Comment: Oh, and always remember to use exit(); after a header-redirect ;) Or else the rest of your code will execute, which can result in quite unwanted results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to redirect `POST` fields that have been sent to the current request (by redirecting with a `307`), but to create them artificially is tricky and depends on if the user has javascript enabled. I use this function, but you shouldn't depend on it working if the user disables javascript.

```
<?php

function createHiddenFields( $value, $name = NULL )
{
    $output = "";
    if( is_array( $value ) ) {
        foreach( $value as $key => $value ) {
            $output .= self::createHiddenFields( $value, is_null( $name ) ? $key : $name."[$key]" );
        }
    } else {
        $output .= sprintf("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"%s\" value=\"%s\" />",
            htmlspecialchars( stripslashes( $name ) ),
            htmlspecialchars( stripslashes( $value ) )
        );
    }
    return $output;
}

function redirectNowWithPost( $url, array $post_array = NULL )
{
    if( is_null( $post_array ) ) { //we want to forward our $_POST fields
        header( "Location: $url", TRUE, 307 );
    } elseif( ! $post_array ) { //we don't have any fields to forward
        header( "Location: $url", TRUE );
    } else { //we have some to forward let's fake a custom post w/ javascript
        ?>
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $url ); ?>" method="post">
<script type="text/javascript">
//this is a hack so that the submit function doesn't get overridden by a field called "submit"
document.forms[0].___submit___ = document.forms[0].submit;
</script>
<?php print createHiddenFields( $post_array ); ?>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.forms[0].___submit___();
</script>
        <?php
    }
    exit();
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CakePHP's inbuilt [redirect function](http://book.cakephp.org/view/982/redirect) for the redirect but the variable will still be visible in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to use POST then, not GET if you do not want it displayed

Comment: A POST Location redirect is not possible.

Comment: You can use CURL to attach postdata to a request.

Comment: I never said POST Location redirect.  If he doesn't want data displayed on the URL then one method to do that is POST

Comment: @cweiske It's not impossible, you just can't do it with HTTP alone. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect to the same host, you can store the data in the session and transmit the session ID via cookie.

Alternatively, you store the data and send a session ID nevertheless. The target system reads the session ID and requests the original data from the original server based on the session ID.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting the variables in a session before redirecting:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['code'] = 2345;
header("Location: http://www.xyz.com");
```

Comment: sry, i was in a rush. i meant to write session instead of get:)). see update.

Comment: Thanks all, am redirecting to different domain, How get the session data in other domain?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a GET parameter in the URL why not set some data to the [session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)?  You can then redirect as normal but the data isn't visible to the user, it's stored on the server side.